# Acesso negado quando coloco duas roles nas rotas usando o Adonis Acl

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, adonisjs

Olá,
Estou tentando fazer com que o administrador e o paciente tenham acesso a algumas rotas do meu sistema. Porém a estrutura só funciona quando coloco somente uma role em `'is:(administrador || paciente)'` no final do código. Quando coloco `'is:administrador'` ou `'is:paciente'` separadamente funciona.

Segui o que a documentação pede(https://www.npmjs.com/package/adonis-acl#protect-routes) mas não tive êxito.

```
Route.group(() => {
  Route.resource("/users", "UserController").only(["update"]).validator("User")
  Route.resource("/users", "UserController").only(["show","destroy"]);
  Route.resource("/pacientes", "PacienteController").only(["store", "show", "update", "destroy"]);
  Route.resource("/dentistas", "DentistaController").only(["index"]);
  Route.resource("/consultas", "ConsultaController").only(["store", "destroy"]);
  Route.resource("/especialidades", "EspecialidadeController").only(["index","show"]);
}).middleware(['auth:jwt', 'is:(administrador || paciente)']);
```

Minhas roles estão criadas corretamente e funcionam em outras rotas

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "administrador",
    "name": "Administrador",
    "description": "Realizar qualquer ação",
    "created_at": "2020-10-22 00:03:46",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-22 00:03:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "dentista",
    "name": "Dentista",
    "description": "Visualiza suas proprias consultas",
    "created_at": "2020-10-22 00:03:56",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-22 00:03:56"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "slug": "paciente",
    "name": "Paciente",
    "description": "Gerencia suas informações e consultas",
    "created_at": "2020-10-22 00:04:02",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-22 00:04:02"
  }
]
```

Comment: Qual é a mensagem que aparece pra você?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente resolver usando `or`, desta forma:

```
Route.group(() => {
  Route.resource("/users", "UserController").only(["update"]).validator("User")
  Route.resource("/users", "UserController").only(["show","destroy"]);
  Route.resource("/pacientes", "PacienteController").only(["store", "show", "update", "destroy"]);
  Route.resource("/dentistas", "DentistaController").only(["index"]);
  Route.resource("/consultas", "ConsultaController").only(["store", "destroy"]);
  Route.resource("/especialidades", "EspecialidadeController").only(["index","show"]);
}).middleware(['auth:jwt', 'is:(administrador or paciente)']);
```

Comment: Opa. Funcionou. Muito obrigado.